# Sharing a FTB LAN world when one of us is offline

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast, hamachi

Me and my friend are using Tunngle to play FTB together using lan. When my friend is unavailable to host I had the idea for him to share the world save on Google Drive. This way I could play the game by myself, send the file back to him and he could host when we play together.

He sent me the file after we played together for a bit. When I put the folder in my save and booted it up I was playing as my friend, same location same inv.

Does anyone know a way that I could play as my own character as I left off when we were playing over Tunngle?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a server.

On minecraft.net you can find an executable file to start a Minecraft server. This allows you to play with your friends at the same time in the same world with different inventories.
*[Here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Setting_up_a_server)'s a tutorial from the Minecraft Wiki about how to setup a Minecraft vanilla server.*
You only will be able to play with your friends in the server world if the server is ON.

If you download the server.jar from the minecraft.net page, you will get a server for a vanilla game.

If your goal is play w/ your friend with a  modded client, here is a link to a tutorial for this. [Minecraft forums](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/support/server-support/server-administration/1896448-guide-how-to-setup-a-minecraft-multiplayer-server)

Comment: Yeah a server ain't gonna work as my buddy is not allowed to port forward  and I can't get it to work due to my ipv6 address. It's super easy for us to play together using tunngle (better than hamachi). I just want to be able to play on our world when he isn't hosting a lan session.

Comment: The MC Forums link is for a Vanilla server only. It doesn't say anything about a modded client.

Comment: @andrewgray-weber So, you want to play with your friend, sharing the same world with different player?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to tell you that your question has already been answered in this thread: [Changing minecraft playerdata when transferring a saved game (open to LAN)?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/197686/changing-minecraft-playerdata-when-transferring-a-saved-game-open-to-lan) .

I hope you do more research before posting in the future :)

Comment: Thanks! I'm having some trouble understanding exactly what to do in the context of FTB. There seems to be some difference in the way the save file is setup.

Comment: Also I don't understand how he is able to "expand" .dat files and delete some of their contents, as shown in the solution.

Comment: Oh, in that case I'll check how FTB works when I get back from work and report back.

Comment: I just figured it out. I have to use NBTexplorer to mess with the .dat files.

Thanks for the help. :)