# unfortunate issue when transferring Minecraft worlds

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, hosting

I have Server.jar 1.16.4 Minecraft server software set up and ready to go, and I want to transfer a world and all contents from the Minecraft world directory to the server.jar world directory. This worked, but my hot-bar and inventory have been cleared and my XP value has been reset back to 0 (previously I was at level 130+).

I would like to keep this as it was in the original world, but have the world running on the server. Is it possible to do such a thing, or must I put all my items in a chest and regain all my levels?

Comment: no, all the data is there, its just that it needs to be in a different place on single player its level.dat i believe and on servers its (uuid here).dat and in a different place i believe

Comment: oh. so all I must do is straight-up transfer the data from "level.dat" to ".dat" and everything will be replaced with what I had in the local world?

Comment: yep, i think thats pretty much it

Comment: you might have to change some of the data though, im not sure

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing minecraft playerdata when transferring a saved game (open to LAN)?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/197686/changing-minecraft-playerdata-when-transferring-a-saved-game-open-to-lan)